# do we have GAMS code Heuristic Algorithem?

Tags: gams-math

Does anyone have an example of implementation of Heuristic Algorithm in GAMS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

GAMS is a modeling language whose job is to translate an optimization model written (semi-)algebraically into the form needed by a solver. It is not a fully functional language like C++ or Python, and is not designed to implement GA, SA, or other algorithms.

Similarly, since GAMS is not designed to run arbitrary types of code, I suspect that it is *not* possible to call MATLAB code from GAMS, though I am not sure about that.